# How can I write Option Distinct on Grid

Tags: genexus

I'd like to display the data on grid.

There are data that have columns such as order id, product id, customer id, store id and order date.
These all are unique data except order date.

I'd like to display only a row when order dates are same.
And I'd like to display rows when order dates are not.

I'm thinking that Option Distinct could be possible it.
Is it truely possible?
Or there's a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The [Unique Property](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?39891,Unique%20property) is exactly for that purpose.